# How can I resume the match when playing offline with bots?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Whenever I enter offline with bots, the match starts paused:

[image: MATCH PAUSED]

Using `pause` and `unpause` commands in the console apply a pause on top of the match pause.

How can I resume the game?

Comment: Did you also try <kbd>pause/break</kbd>? And I believe there was some console command like `pausable` or `sv_pausable` to make the game pause-able.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be something caused by spectating matches in GOTV in the same session as trying to play with bots. Restarting the game and going to the offline match first before anything else works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Just type the following command into the console:

```
mp_unpause_match
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sv_pausable 1
```

in order to have the ability to set :

```
pause
```

and

```
unpause
```